# C++ application: Passing a value from a form to the main window private variable

Tags: c++, qt

I am developing an application to feed a database. My main window is basically a menu that opens forms for different utilities.
Not sure if it's the best practice but let me explain what I'm trying to do:
my class mainwindow has a private QString that will store the current project name. In the menu, "Load" opens the form (another class) that lists all the existing projects in a combobox. The user chooses the project he wants and clicks OK.

I would like to return the combobox.currentText() into the dedicated private variable. After some research I still cannot figure out how to make it, wether I should use SIGNAL from the form to trigger a SLOT of the mainform or if there is a simple way to just return a value after pressing OK (such as an input dialog). If i am not clear enough, maybe the following sketch could help.

[image]

I definitively have a lack of knowledge on the subject but would be grateful for some help.

Comment: Have you already implemented the opening of the form? Who opens it? Is it a slot that has been connected to the `triggered` signal of the `Load` action?

Comment: Hi Benjamin. Yes indeed it is a slot that opens the LOADPROJECT form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed if your form for loading a project would emit a signal `currentProjectChanged` as soon as the user accepts the form (presses the `OK` button), this signal could be connected to a slot of the main window. For simple things this may be fine and elegant.

On the other hand reacting on actions sometimes needs more logic. If your action triggers a slot that cares for action execution, this slot probably should implement the logic. It should open the form and check whether the user has accepted the project change (pressed `OK`). In this case the action execution slot could get the new project name from the form and call a main window method to pass the new project name.

Comment: I managed to get the value following the "elegant" way. But I will try your second suggestion later on. Thanks for the guidance.